# Is it possible to update a Keychain item's kSecAttrAccessible value?

Tags: iphone, security, ios, ipad, keychain

Is it possible to update the value of the attribute `kSecAttrAccessible` of existing items in the Keychain? It seems that it cannot be changed after the item was added to the Keychain. The following steps back up my assumption.

Add a new item to the Keychain:

```
NSData *encodedIdentifier = [@"BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER" 
                             dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *encodedPassword = [@"PASSWORD"
                           dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

// Construct a Keychain item
NSDictionary *keychainItem = 
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        kSecClassGenericPassword, kSecClass,
        encodedIdentifier, kSecAttrGeneric,
        encodedIdentifier, kSecAttrService,
        @"USERNAME", kSecAttrAccount,
        kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlocked, kSecAttrAccessible,
        encodedPassword, kSecValueData
        nil];

// Add item to Keychain
OSStatus addItemStatus = SecItemAdd((CFDictionaryRef)keychainItem, NULL);
```

At a later time, change the attribute `kSecAttrAccessible` from `kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlocked` to `kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlock`:

```
NSData *encodedIdentifier = [@"BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER" 
                             dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSDictionary *query = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                       kSecClassGenericPassword, kSecClass,
                       encodedIdentifier, kSecAttrGeneric,
                       encodedIdentifier, kSecAttrService,
                       nil];

NSDictionary *updatedAttributes = 
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlock 
                                forKey:kSecAttrAccessible];

OSStatus updateItemStatus = SecItemUpdate((CFDictionaryRef)query, 
                                          (CFDictionaryRef)updatedAttributes);
```

The problem with this approach is that `updateItemStatus` always results in the status `errSecUnimplemented`.

I think it should be possible to update the value of `kSecAttrAccessible` because requirements of applications change. What if an application added ten items to the Keychain in the past without specifying the protection class with `kSecAttrAccessible`. The Keychain implicitly assigns new items the value `kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlocked` if the protection class is not set explicitly by the developer. Later, the developer needs to change the protection class to `kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlock` because the application must access it in the background (Multitasking). How can the developer accomplish that?

There is already a thread in the Apple Developer Forums, but it has not yielded an answer yet: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/87646?tstart=0

Answer (score 26, accepted):

After opening a support incident at Apple Developer Technical Support (ADTS), I received a reply that answers this question. `SecItemUpdate()` requires the Keychain item's data via the attribute `kSecValueData` to perform the update of the attribute `kSecAttrAccessible`. According to ADTS, this constraint is currently not documented in the reference documentation.

```
NSData *encodedIdentifier = [@"BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER" 
                             dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *query = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                       kSecClassGenericPassword, kSecClass,
                       encodedIdentifier, kSecAttrGeneric,
                       encodedIdentifier, kSecAttrService,
                       nil];

// Obtain the Keychain item's data via SecItemCopyMatching()
NSData *itemData = ...;

NSDictionary *updatedAttributes = 
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlock, kSecAttrAccessible,
        (CFDataRef)itemData, kSecValueData,
        nil];

OSStatus updateItemStatus = SecItemUpdate((CFDictionaryRef)query, 
                                          (CFDictionaryRef)updatedAttributes);

// updateItemStatus should have the value errSecSuccess
```

Comment: It is now [documented](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/kSecAttrAccessible) to be needed in iOS 4 and earlier.

Comment: If you're using RSA key pairs, make sure to do this for *both* keys.

Comment: @PatrickGoley I need help to read my Private key when device lock
do you have any idea how should I set `kSecAttrAccessible` during generating Keypair?
how should I set `kSecAttrAccessible` to read it?
my problem is only for keypair.
thank you

Comment: This is not working. Has anybody got a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to get the other answer to work.  I ended up testing kSecAttrAccessibile and if it wasn't what I wanted I recorded the value and attributes in the keychain in local variables, reset the keychain, set kSecAttrAccessible as desired and then set the value and attributes in the keychain to their original settings.

Comment: You don't happen to have a code snippet for this do you? Having trouble getting this to work