# Update Keychain kSecAttrAccessible with SecItemUpdate returns -50

Tags: ios, objective-c, keychain, security-framework

I'm trying to update the kSecAttrAccessible of my Keychain item based on [mbinna](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369238/is-it-possible-to-update-a-keychain-items-ksecattraccessible-value) question's.

The problem is that the following code returns -50 for the `updateItemStatus` variable. I took I look in a [similar question about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30337083/ios-keychain-secitemupdate-returns-50-paramerr-when-updating-ksecattraccessi) then removed the `kSecReturnRef` attribute from my query (`newQuery`), but its still not working and returning -50, which means "One or more parameters passed to a function were not valid."

What am I doing wrong?

```
NSString *privateKeyAttrTag = @"mykeytag";

NSDictionary *getQuery = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        kSecClassKey, kSecClass, 
        privateKeyAttrTag, kSecAttrApplicationTag, 
        kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA, kSecAttrKeyType, 
        @YES, kSecReturnRef, 
        kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlocked, kSecAttrAccessible, nil];

CFTypeRef dataTypeRef = NULL;
OSStatus status = SecItemCopyMatching(
    (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)getQuery, &dataTypeRef);

if (status==errSecSuccess && dataTypeRef != NULL) {
    NSData *data = (__bridge NSData *)dataTypeRef;

    NSDictionary *newQuery = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        kSecClassKey, kSecClass,
        privateKeyAttrTag, kSecAttrApplicationTag,
        kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA, kSecAttrKeyType,
        kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlocked, kSecAttrAccessible, nil];

    NSDictionary *updateAttrs = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: 
        kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlock, kSecAttrAccessible,
        (CFDataRef)data, kSecValueData, nil];

    OSStatus updateItemStatus = SecItemUpdate(
            (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)newQuery, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)updateAttrs);

    // updateItemStatus == -50, which means "One or more parameters passed to a function were not valid."

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because `dataTypeRef` is not the `NSData` it self, it is a `Dictionary` which contains the data.

The complete code:

```
NSString *keyTag = @"mykeytag";

NSDictionary *getQuery = @{
                        (NSString *)kSecClass:              (NSString *)kSecClassKey,
                        (NSString *)kSecAttrApplicationTag: keyTag,
                        (NSString *)kSecAttrKeyType:        (NSString *)kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
                        (NSString *)kSecReturnRef:          @YES,
                        (NSString *)kSecAttrAccessible:     (NSString *)kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlocked,
                        (NSString *)kSecReturnData:         @YES
                        };

CFDictionaryRef item = NULL;
OSStatus status = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)getQuery, (CFTypeRef *)&item);

if (status == errSecSuccess && item != NULL) {
    NSDictionary *itemDictionary = (__bridge_transfer NSDictionary *)item;

    NSMutableDictionary *updateItem = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:itemDictionary];
    [updateItem setObject:[getQuery objectForKey:(id)kSecClass] forKey:(id)kSecClass];

    NSData *data = itemDictionary[(id)kSecValueData];

    NSDictionary *attributesToUpdate = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    (NSString *)kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlock,
                                    kSecAttrAccessible,
                                    (CFDataRef)data,
                                    kSecValueData,
                                    nil];

    OSStatus updateItemStatus = SecItemUpdate((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)updateItem,
                                            (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)attributesToUpdate);
}
```